# Why $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Why $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$?
Would you give me a simple proof or the outline of the proof?

Comment: Another approach is the use of Hahn-Banach separation theorem: because of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28788/proof-of-f-g-in-l1-loc-if-f-and-g-act-equally-on-c-c-infty) theorem and Riesz's Representation Theorem, every continuous linear functional on $L^p$ with $1\le p<\infty$ that vanishes on $C_o^\infty$ is identically zero.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The outline (the proof isn't simple, at least not according to my understanding of simple):

Let $f \in L^p$. Then there is a sequence of simple functions $s_n \in L^p$ that converges pointwise to $f$. Then you show that they converge in norm.

These $s_n$ have finite support. You can therefore apply Lusin's theorem:

(Lusin) Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ a Radon measure and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ a $\mu$-measurable function with finite support $E$. Then for every $\delta > 0$ there exists a closed set $K \subset E$ such that $\mu(E \setminus K) < \delta$ and $f$ is continuous on $K$.

to get a sequence of continuous functions.

Then you apply Tietze's theorem:

(Tietze) If $\Omega$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $K \subset \Omega$ compact then any $f \in C(K, \mathbb R)$ can be extended to a bounded function in $C(\Omega, \mathbb R)$.

to get a sequence of compactly supported functions.

I did this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66999/c-cx-dense-in-l-1x) for $p=1$.

Once you have $C_c$ dense in $L^p$ you mollify. Which I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/smooth-functions-with-compact-support-are-dense-in-l1). Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using $C_0$ to mean compactly supported functions. This might of course not be right since you could be using $C_0$ to denote functions vanishing at infinity.

Comment: @ Matt N. Really thanks!

Comment: The approach with Lusin's theorem is also explained in detail in the chapter about $L^p$ spaces in Rudins "Real and Complex Analysis".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but rather than using convolution and Lusins Lemma to approximate continuous finitely supported functions I would use the functions

$$
f(x) :=
\begin{cases}
e^{1-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} & \text{ for } \vert x\vert <1 \\
0,& otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$
g_n(x) := \frac{1}{n}\tan(\frac{x ~\pi }{2})
$$

to approximate indicator functions $\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$ by the functions $\frac{a+b}{2}+ \frac{b-a}{2} f\circ g_n (x)$.

Comment: Note that the proof theorem for case $L^p (R)$ is significantly easier than the general case (where function defined  on LCHS with Radon measure)..