# Explanation on a "different" proof that $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

> **Theorem:** Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $1\leq p < \infty$. The space $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Haim Brezis has a French book called "[Analyse fonctionnelle: theorie et applications](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Analyse_fonctionnelle.html?id=aykKPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)" (my version, Análysis Functional: Teoría y aplicaciones, is Spanish) that says:

*We know that $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^1(\Omega)$. So, we can suppose $1<p< \infty$. To prove that $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ it's enough to show that if $h\in L^{p'}(\Omega)$ satisfies $$\int_\Omega hu=0\,\textit{ for all }\,u\in C_c(\Omega),$$ then $h=0$.*

Here $p'$ is a number such that $1/p+1/p'=1$. Could someone explain me why is it enough to prove it?

Note: The rest of the proof is to show that $h$ is locally integrable to conclude that $$\int_\Omega hu=0\text{ for all }u\in C_c(\Omega)\Rightarrow h=0.$$

This proof seems "different" of other proofs ([like this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/156451/70305)) that uses, for example, approximation by simple functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me a reference where I can find proof that $C_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira Theorem 2.19 of [Adams book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=R5A65Koh-EoC&pg=PA31&dq=%22Approximation+by+Continuous+Functions%22+adams&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio6vqIrcPlAhUDzlkKHfB_BuQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Approximation%20by%20Continuous%20Functions%22%20adams&f=false).

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira The strongest result for $C_c^\infty$ can be found in [Brezis Book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=1bFCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&dq=%22introduced+by+Leray+and+Friedrichs%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMlIuUq8PlAhWnxVkKHT4AC-YQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22introduced%20by%20Leray%20and%20Friedrichs%22&f=false) (Corollary 4.23). The same argument is presented in Section 1.2.3 of [Espaços de Sobolev](http://www.dmm.im.ufrj.br/~medeiros/LinkedDocuments/livroespsobolev.pdf) by [Medeiros](http://www.dmm.im.ufrj.br/~medeiros/) (in portuguese).

Comment: Thanks Pedro! The proof is interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is what is going on : Let $X$ denote the closure of $C_c(\Omega)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, you want to show that $X = L^p(\Omega)$. Suppose not, then by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there must exist a continuous linear function $\varphi : L^p(\Omega) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\varphi(u) = 0 \quad\forall u \in C_c(\Omega)
$$
but $\varphi \neq 0$.

Now, the dual of $L^p$ is $L^{p'}$, so that means that there should exist $h \in L^{p'}$ such that
$$
\int hu = 0 \quad\forall u \in C_c(\Omega), \text{ but } h \neq 0
$$
This is what you are trying to contradict. (ie. if no such $h$ exists, then it must happen that $X = L^p(\Omega)$)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been already wonderfully answered, I think it's worth to share this nice proposition, useful to deal with density of subspaces in normed vector spaces (the proof relies on Hahn-Banach):

Let $(F,\| \cdot \|_F )$ be a normed vector space and let $A \subset F$ be a subspace which **is not** dense in $F$ and let $x_0 \in (F \setminus \overline{A})$. Then there exists a bounded linear functional $f \in A^{*}$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and

$$ f(x)=0 \ \ \ \forall x \in \overline{A}  $$