# Question about this problem If $u \in H^1(U)$, then $Du=0$ a.e. on the set $\{u=0\}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

In this problem [If $u \in H^1(U)$, then $Du=0$ a.e. on the set $\{u=0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108657/if-u-in-h1u-then-du-0-a-e-on-the-set-u-0?rq=1)

**I don't understand this part:**

$$ \int_U \partial_i u^\epsilon\,v\,dx\to  0\tag w$$
for all $v\in L^2(U)$, but now we only need to prove that 
$$ \int_U \partial_i u^\epsilon\,v\,dx\to  0\tag 1$$
for all $v\in C_c^\infty(U)$

Why instead of all $v \in L^2(U)$, we only need to prove for all $v \in C_c^{\infty}(U)$ in $$ \int_U \partial_i u^\epsilon\,v\,dx\to  0\tag 1?$$

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only because that $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$, but also you have to relay on something from functional analysis. In my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1108717/124358), which you already noticed, I call for help from the following lemma from Functional Analysis:

---

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $S$ be a total subset of $X^*$, i.e., the span of $S$ is dense in $X^*$, $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ and $x\in X$ is given. Then $x_n\to x$ weakly as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $({x_n})$ is bounded and 
$$
\left<{y^*,x_n}\right>\to\left<{y^*,x}\right>\text{ for all }y^*\in S.
$$
Here the boundness of $(x_n)$ is **very** important.

---

Notice that from the question itself you already proved that $u_\epsilon$ is bounded in $H^1$ norm, hence, $\nabla u_\epsilon$ is bounded in $L^2$ norm. Therefore, from lemma I mentioned above, we have, instead using $L^2$ as the test function for weak $L^2$ convergence, we could only use the dense set of it, i.e., the $C_c^\infty$ function, and hence addressed your problem.

Notice that we use this fact **many** times in Sobolev space theory, especially when using the density argument.

Comment: Can I ask what is $X^*$?

Comment: @Sherry It denotes the dual space of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** $C_c^\infty(U)$ is dense in $L^2(U)$.
Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535854/explanation-on-a-different-proof-that-c-c-omega-is-dense-in-lp-omega?lq=1) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133496/reference-for-c-c-infty0-th-dense-in-l20-th).

Comment: Could you please tell me where this theorem come from? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, it is not me that downvote you.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you another question? In that problem, when proving $u^{\epsilon} \to 0$ weakly in $H^1(u)$, do we need $\epsilon \to 0$ or $u \to 0$?

Comment: @Sherry I'm not sure to understand this question. thanks.

Comment: I think it is $\epsilon \to 0$, but dragon, who ask the question is assuming $u \to 0$. It really confuses me.