# If $\mu$ has no atoms, then $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} *\mu$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, having no atomic points.

How to prove that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} *\mu$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Here $f * \mu(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(z-w)d\mu(w)$, where $z=(x,y)$.

Comment: Have you tried approximating $f$ by continuous function? A brief explanation of some of your attempts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As your function $f(x,y):=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous and bounded belongs to $L_1(\mu)$, and so there is some $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $\|f-g\|_1 <\epsilon $ (as $C_c$ is dense in any $L_p$ space of any Euclidean space equiped with a Radon measure). Then its easy to see that
$$
|f*\mu(z_1)-f*\mu(z_0)|\leqslant 2\epsilon +\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|g(z_1-w)-g(z_0-w)|\mathop{}\!d \mu(w)
$$
As the support of $g$ is compact then finally from the definition of compactness we can see that $g(z_1-\cdot )\to g(z_0-\cdot )$ uniformly as $z_1\to z_0$, so we conclude that $f*\mu$ is continuous. (Note that we don't need that $\mu$ will be atomless.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two problems: (1) I think that your solution assumes some translation-invariance of the measure $\mu$, which I did not assume. That is, it seems to me that you need $\mu(w-B)=\mu(B)$ for every $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, to deduce that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(z_1-w)-g(z_1-w)|d\mu(w)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(w)-g(w)|d\mu(w)$. (2) I did not assume that $\mu$ is Radon, so I am not sure that you can use the density of compactly supported functions in $L^1$. Anyway, I think that the first point is the most problematic.

Comment: You can see that the measure $\mu$ need to be translation-invariant, by taking $g=0,f=\chi_A$ for some $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Im not assuming translation invariance as if $g(z_1-\cdot )o g(z_0-\cdot )$ uniformly then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|g(z_1-w)-g(z_0-w)|\mathop{}\!d \mu(w)\leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \epsilon d\mu(x)=\epsilon $$ when $|z_1-z_0|<\delta $ for suitable $\delta >0$. That $\mu$ is atomless is also un-needed, what plays the fundamental role there is the uniform convergence

Comment: Im using the fact that $C_c$ is dense in $L_1$, I can't choose $g$ arbitrarily, by example that $g=0$. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170456/c-cx-dense-in-lp). Also note that any probability measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Radon.

Answer (score 0):

I now think it is rather easy, actually:

Set $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$. Suppose that $z_n \to z_0$. Then the functions
$$
f_n(w):=f(z_n-w) \to f_0(w):=f(z_0-w),
$$
for every $w$ except $w=z_0$.

Thus $f_n $ converges pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{z_0\}$ to $f_0$.

Since $\mu$ have no atomic points, $\mu(\{z_0\})=0$, so $f_n \to f_0$ pointwise $\mu$-a.e on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Since $f \le 1$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure, the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem implies that
$$
\int f_n(w)d\mu(w) \to \int f_0d\mu(w),
$$
which implies the claim.

The same result would be true for any bounded function, which has a finite number of discontinuities.

Comment: this seems correct also, but note again that atomless is un-needed, the statement will work also for any atomic measure, you have that $|f_n(w)-f_0(w)|\to 0$ pointwise for all $w\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $|f_n-f_0|\leqslant  2$, so the result follow from the dominated convergence theorem